# Javascript, Regex - I need to grab each section of a string contained in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's what I need in what I guess must be the right order:

1. The contents of each section of the string contained in square brackets (which each must follow after the rest of the original string) need to be extracted out and stored, and the original string returned without them.
2. If there is a recognized string followed by a colon at the start of a given extracted section, then I need that identified and removed.
3. For what's left (comma delimited), I need it dumped into an array.
4. Do not attempt to parse nested brackets.

What is a good way to do this?

**Edit:** Here's an example of a string:

> hi, i'm a string [this: is, how] [it: works, but, there] [might be bracket, parts, without, colons   ] [[nested sections should be ignored?]]

**Edit:** Here's what might be the results:

> After extraction: 'hi, i'm a string'
>
> Array identified as 'this': ['is', 'how']
>
> Array identified as 'it': ['works', 'but', 'there']
>
> Array identified without a label: ['might by bracket', 'parts', 'without', 'colons']
>
> Array identified without a label: []

Comment: Could you give an example string and the corresponding result?

Comment: A quick note - it is possible you *are* attempting to parse nested brackets. What if you had `[token: val1, [ignore] val2]` ? Even in your example, the nested token causes some trouble.

Comment: Edit: Hmm.  Well, I suppose if there's any nested tokens, the whole set should probably not be parsed, then.  Would that be an option?

Comment: You can easily check from them, search for `\\[[^\\]]*\\[` .

Comment: Does that only check in the case of [[ and ]]?  Or does that also check for your example?

Comment: It should cover all nested tokens. It searches for `[`+`not closing it` + `another [`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var results = [];
s = s.replace(/\[+(?:(\w+):)?(.*?)\]+/g,
      function(g0, g1, g2){
        results.push([g1, g2.split(',')]);
        return "";
      });
```

Gives the results:

```
>> results =
  [["this", [" is", " how"]],
   ["it", [" works", " but", " there"]],
   ["", ["might be bracket", " parts", " without", " colons "]],
   ["", ["nested sections should be ignored?"]]
  ]

>> s = "hi, i'm a string     "
```

Note it leaves spaces between tokens. Also, you can remove `[[]]` tokens in an earlier stage by calling `s = s.replace(/\[\[.*?\]\]/g, '');` - this code captures them as a normal group.

Comment: Yes, you'll want to use a regex, like `.split(/\s*,\s*/)`. A string doesn't work the same way, and `/g` isn't needed in `split` (but doesn't hut either  `:)` )

Comment: Ah, /\s*,\s*/.  I'm still not completely clear on what /g does exactly.

Comment: `/g` is **global**. When you `match` without `/g`, it only finds the first match, which is undesirable in most cases. `split`, however, works as expected with or without it.

Comment: While this works, it leaves you with a seemingly "unwieldly" result.  Personally, I would prefer to separate the string into parts using something like `str.split(/\s+(?=\[+)/);`, then iterate over the results afterwards.

Comment: @Andy - I agree, it can be written more clearly that way. With more edge cases, that will be the only option.